# MongoDB Query - Get frequency map of an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("id-1"),
    "tests": [
      {
        "category": "cat1",
        "status": "status1",
      },
      {
        "category": "cat1",
        "status": "status2",
      },
      {
        "category": "cat2",
        "status": "status2",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("id-2"),
    "tests": [
      {
        "category": "cat2",
        "status": "status1",
      },
      {
        "category": "cat1",
        "status": "status1",
      },
      {
        "category": "cat1",
        "status": "status2",
      },
    ],
  }
]
```

I have the above collection, my intention is to generate the below result. Please note that the statuses and categories are dynamic.

```
[
    {
        "id" : id-1,
        "status": {
            "status1": count,
            "status2": count
        },
        "category": {
            "cat1": count  of it,
            "cat2": count  of it
        }
    },
    {
        "id" : id-2,
        "status": {
            "status1": count  of it,
            "status2": count  of it
        },
        "category": {
            "cat1": count  of it,
            "cat2": count  of it
        }
    }
]
```

What I've attempted to do till now, is

1. Unwinded tests field, then

```
{
        "$group": {
          "_id": {
            "id": "$_id",
            "testStatus": "$tests.status"
          },
          "val": {
            "$sum": 1
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": {
            "id": "$_id.id",
            
          },
          "resGroup": {
            "$addToSet": {
              k: "$_id.testStatus",
              v: "$val"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "_id": "$_id.id",
          "statusGroup": {
            "$arrayToObject": "$resGroup"
          }
        }
      }
```

I've done the same for the category field and used `$facet` to run multiple aggregations.

But, am unable to fetch the result in the required format.

Any help on this will be appreciated.
Thanks

MongoDB Version: 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$map` to iterate loop of `tests` array and convert the object to an array using `$objectToArray`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `tests` array
- `$unwind` again deconstruct `tests` array because it's a nested array
- `$group` by `_id`, `k`, and `v` and get the total count
- `$group` by `_id` and `k` and construct the array of the status field in `items`
- `$arrayToObject` convert `items` key-value array to an object
- `$group` by `_id` and construct the array of `items`
- `$arrayToObject` convert `items` array to object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      tests: {
        $map: {
          input: "$tests",
          in: { $objectToArray: "$$this" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$tests" },
  { $unwind: "$tests" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        k: "$tests.k",
        v: "$tests.v"
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id._id",
        k: "$_id.k"
      },
      items: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.v",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      items: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.k",
          v: { $arrayToObject: "$items" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $project: { items: { $arrayToObject: "$items" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KYjwvm_2T5G)